# How to encrypt all Excel Workbook in the same folder?

Tags: r, iteration, xlsx

I exported a dataframe to xlsx according to their filter (Country) into the same folder based on the following script

```
df = data.frame(Country = c("Japan", "Japan", "Thailand", "Germany", "Thailand", "Japan"), 
                            Count = c(15, 5, 25, 5, 60, 50))

#Separate the dataframe according to their respective country
splitdf = split(df, df$Country)

#apply style and export
save_data <- function(df, name) {
  wb <- createWorkbook()
  addWorksheet(wb, name)
  writeDataTable(wb, name, df, tableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2")
  saveWorkbook(wb, paste0(name, ".xlsx"), overwrite = TRUE)
}

mapply(
  save_data,
  splitdf,
  names(splitdf)
)
```

I understand that I can encrypt them using the write.xlsx function individually but I am not sure how to do it with multiple files such as this.

```
write.xlsx(x, file, sheetName="Sheet1", col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, 
           append=FALSE, showNA=TRUE, **password=NULL**)
```

Comment: @IRTFM hi sorry for the late reply, I have update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical process for handling results from `split` is to then use `lapply` on the result. This is essentially the inspiration for Hadley's plyr package, which he then transmorgrified to the dply package and its tidyverse cousins.

```
 lapply( split(df, df$Country) , function(x){ save_data(x, x$Country) }
```

But it seems you already are aware of how to do that with `mapply` and only wnat to use `write.xlsx`. There are two packages with functions having that name in my library but only `xlsx::write.xlsx` has a password parameter, so I'm guessing that is the one to demonstrate:

```
if ( !require(xlsx) ){install.packages("xlsx", dependencies=TRUE); require(xlsx) }

lapply( split(df, df$Country), function(x) {
        xlsx::write.xlsx(x, file=paste0(x$Country,".xlsx"), col.names=TRUE, 
        row.names=TRUE, append=FALSE, showNA=TRUE, password="test")})   # FAIL
```

The error I got was that there was no java function by some name that I could not make sense of, but testing with the first example in the `write.xlsx` help page showed no error and I looked again, realizing that I had forgotten to take just the first item in the Country column, so this succeeds:

```
lapply( split(df, df$Country), function(x) {xlsx::write.xlsx(x,
                      file=paste0(x$Country[1],".xlsx"), # make length 1
                      col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=FALSE,
                      showNA=TRUE,  password="test")})
```

The fact that you see a named list of Nulls as teh console result does not indicate failure. The `write.xlsx` function works via its side-effects. (The password feature was tested with LibreCalc on a Linux box.) One could use a `paste0` call to make the passwords some that was file-specific.

You could have used your `mapply` method by supplying a `MoreArgs` parameter after the first two arguments 'split_df' and 'names(split_df)'

```
  ........, MoreArgs=list( col.names=TRUE, 
                    row.names=TRUE, append=FALSE, showNA=TRUE, 
                    password="test")  ) #extra paren to close the `mapply` call
```